# Why QMimeData is returning invalid QStringList at each call of member func formats()?

Tags: qt, c++11, foreach, qt5

I was trying to use a for each [Modern c++ style] but the code is crashed each time!
It was something like :

```
for(auto &k:mimeData->formats())
{ ... }
```

And later out of my surprises I found that the QStringList returned by formats is either invalid or completely separate object though the internal data is ought to be same!
So I tried to figure out in more simple example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMimeData>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    cout<<boolalpha;

    list<string> ls;
    cout<<(ls.begin() != ls.end())<<"\n";

    QStringList qsl;
    cout<<(qsl.begin() != qsl.end())<<"\n";

    QMimeData qme;

    cout<<(qme.formats().begin() != qme.formats().end())<<"\n";
    cout<<"OMG! is it empty? ->  "<<qme.formats().empty()<<"\n";

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output is something like :

```
false
false
true
OMG! is it empty? ->  true
```

Until or unless I take an rvalue reference I cant decide what is happening internally!

I really  need a solution to use it with range based for loops, not Qt's foreach!

P.S. I dont want to copy it to avoid O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, there's no guarantee `QMimeData` class keeps `QStringList` of supported formats (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#formats) as a field.

The source code supports that (Qt5.4/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmimedata.cpp:593):

```
QStringList QMimeData::formats() const
{
    Q_D(const QMimeData);
    QStringList list;
    for (int i=0; i<d->dataList.size(); i++)
        list += d->dataList.at(i).format;
    return list;
}
```

Therefore this list is constructed on *every* call to `formats()`. Farther calls to it will always yield a separate container.

Since you do need to preserve it to traverse it, I'd recommend keeping a local copy of it. Do note that C++11 allows for it to be moved constructed (or in fact - [optimized even better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)).

Comment: Will the object be alive if I hold it as an rvalue reference?


LIKE :


`
{
   auto &&formatList = mimeData->formats();
   ...
   //end of block   
}
`

Comment: @pPanda_beta - there's no guarantee for that, as you'd be using a reference to a local (and destroyed) variable. Do note that if you assign it to a regular variable with RVO the object will be - think of this way - created in place of the call.